# Получить информацию о производителе RAM

Tags: c#

Мне нужно получить полную информацию по модулям оперативной памяти. Я пытался сделать это через WMI:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher12 = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");

Console.WriteLine("------------- Win32_PhysicalMemory instance --------");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher12.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "BankLabel: {0} ; 
        Capacity: {1} Gb; 
        Speed: {2}; 
        Manufacturer: {3}; 
        Serial Number: {4}", 
        queryObj["BankLabel"],
        Math.Round(System.Convert.ToDouble(queryObj["Capacity"]) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2),
        queryObj["Speed"], 
        queryObj["Manufacturer"], 
        queryObj["Name"]);
}
```

Но этого значения там попросту нет. Есть ли иные способы узнать эти данные?

Comment: Есть подозрение что если вы получите доступ к I2C шине, вы получите все что вам нужно и даже больше. Но это не C# почти наверняка

Comment: Этого названия может и не быть, если память NoName, с честными брендовыми планками обычно таких проблем нет. Вообще любые данные кроме значений технических параметров, которые нужны для правильной настройки, не обязаны присутствовать, это дополнительная информация, которую производитель может предоставлять на своих устройствах, а может и не предоставлять, как ему захочется, на работу это не влияет. С большой вероятностью на самих планках памяти у вас тоже нет сведений о производителе.

Answer (score 6):

```
var connection = new ConnectionOptions() { Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate };
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");

scope.Connect();

var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("____________________");
    foreach (PropertyData data in queryObj.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name + "\t" + data.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
____________________
BankLabel               BANK 0
Capacity                4294967296
Caption Physical Memory 
CreationClassName       Win32_PhysicalMemory
DataWidth               64
Description             Physical Memory
DeviceLocator           ChannelA-DIMM0
FormFactor              8
HotSwappable
InstallDate
InterleaveDataDepth     2
InterleavePosition      1
Manufacturer            Kingston
MemoryType              0
Model
Name                    Physical Memory
OtherIdentifyingInfo
PartNumber              99U5402-052.A00LF
PositionInRow
PoweredOn
Removable
Replaceable
SerialNumber            4E1ECEFF
SKU
Speed                   1600
Status
Tag     Physical Memory 0
TotalWidth              64
TypeDetail              128
Version
```

Comment: дело в том, что имя моей карты не отображается при этом. А мне нужно его каким-то образом вытянуть